# Difference between feature_contribs and feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

XGBoost API has two data points that it exposes regarding the features

1. **Feature importance** which can be accessed by 
   xgb_bst.get_score(importance_type='gain')

The documents explain these as :
Get feature importance of each feature. Importance type can be defined as:
‘gain’: the average gain across all splits the feature is used in.

2. **Feature contributions** which can be accessed by
   feature_contribs = xgb_bst.predict(dtest, pred_contribs=True)

Per documentation, output will be a matrix of size (nsample, nfeats + 1) with each record indicating the feature contributions (SHAP values) for that prediction. The sum of all feature contributions is equal to the raw untransformed margin value of the prediction.

My question here is,

1. What is the correlation between the two, since from what I see a feature with maximum
   importance (high gain) is not necessarily the top
   contributor(positive) for most of the individual data and vice
   versa?
2. Intutively, how do I interpret feature importance vs Feature
   contribs? How do they differ?

Comment: I end up with the same question. Did you get an explanation elsewhere?